# "seasonal" R package not playing nice with shiny for input variables

Tags: r, shiny

I have been using the excellent 'seasonal' R package for X11/X13 ARIMA analysis, but I am seeing some erratic behavior with the `series()` call when using `input$` parameters in the `seas()` call.

```
fit_x <- seas(x = tv, x11 = "", forecast.maxlead = as.numeric(input$months),
forecast.probability = as.numeric(input$interval))
# R executes the above statement ok
x_fc <- series(fit_x, "forecast.forecasts")
# this doesn't work

fit_x <- seas(x = tv, x11 = "", forecast.maxlead = 12, forecast.probability = 0.90)
# R executes the above statement ok
x_fc <- series(fit_x, "forecast.forecasts")
# this does work
```

The stack trace is:

```
Warning: Error in seas: object 'input' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    68: seas
    67: eval
    66: eval
    65: reeval
    64: series
    63: observeEventHandler [/Users/koen/Shiny R/Apps/html/server.R#93]
     1: runApp
```

Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest working with seasonal output object directly instead of calling `series()` function. I have not tried to do this but I reckon that referring to a list object is less prone to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying my original answer. I didn't realized you are talking about a shiny input element (guess I should read the title...)

The problem is that the `series` function re-evaluates the call to seas, so it uses `input$months` in an `eval` statement which won't work.

Two simple ways around the problem:

1. Avoid re-evaluation by forcing `seas` to save the forecast output:

   ```
   fit_x <- seas(x = AirPassengers, x11 = "", 
   forecast.maxlead = as.numeric(input$months),
   forecast.probability = as.numeric(input$interval), 
   forecast.save = "fct")
   ```

   Since the forecasts are already present in the `seas` output, re-evaluation becomes unnecessary and the error shouldn't occur. Beside solving the problem, this will also double execution speed.
2. Save the input in intermediate variables (ok, kind of obivious):

   ```
   a <- as.numeric(input$months)
   b <- as.numeric(input$interval)
   fit_x <- seas(x = AirPassengers, x11 = "", forecast.maxlead = a, forecast.probability = b)
   ```